# cling compile error with MinGW: exception handling

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, cling

I am trying to compile cling with MinGw on Windows 7.
It fails at 90% with the following error:

```
C:\cling\src\tools\cling\lib\Interpreter\Exception.cpp:44:62: error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable
           cling::InvalidDerefException::DerefType::NULL_DEREF);
                                                              ^
```

I used these commands to build it:

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="c:/cling" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="C:/Qt/Qt5.14.1/Tools/mingw730_32/bin/gcc.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="C:/Qt/Qt5.14.1/Tools/mingw730_32/bin/g++.exe" ..\src
cmake --build .
```

I tried to add -fexceptions to the cmake tags like this:
`-DCMAKE_CXXFLAGS="-fexceptions"`
and this:
`-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fexceptions"`
but it doesn't help, I get the same error.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

**Edit:**

I was trying to avoid this but I modified the files `\tools\cling\lib\Interpreter\CMakeLists.txt` and `\tools\cling\lib\UserInterface\CMakeLists.txt` to get rid of this error.
I changed `if (UNIX)` to `if (LLVM_COMPILER_IS_GCC_COMPATIBLE)`.

Then I got `wchar_t` conversion errors like this:
`error: cannot convert 'LPTSTR {aka char*}' to 'const wchar_t*'` so I added `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-DUNICODE -D_UNICODE"` to the 
cmake call:

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="c:/cling" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="C:/Qt/Qt5.14.1/Tools/mingw730_32/bin/gcc.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="C:/Qt/Qt5.14.1/Tools/mingw730_32/bin/g++.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-DUNICODE -D_UNICODE" ..\src
```

Now I get the following errors:

```
C:\cling\src\tools\cling\lib\Utils\PlatformWin.cpp: In function 'int cling::utils::platform::windows::GetVisualStudioVersionCompiledWith()':
C:\cling\src\tools\cling\lib\Utils\PlatformWin.cpp:380:11: error: '_MSC_VER' was not declared in this scope
   return (_MSC_VER / 100) - 6;
           ^~~~~~~~
C:\cling\src\tools\cling\lib\Utils\PlatformWin.cpp:380:11: note: suggested alternative: '_TSCHAR'
   return (_MSC_VER / 100) - 6;
           ^~~~~~~~
           _TSCHAR
C:\cling\src\tools\cling\lib\Utils\PlatformWin.cpp: In function 'const void* cling::utils::platform::DLSym(const string&, std::__cxx11::string*)':
C:\cling\src\tools\cling\lib\Utils\PlatformWin.cpp:614:42: error: invalid conversion from 'FARPROC {aka int (__attribute__((__stdcall__)) *)()}' to 'v
oid*' [-fpermissive]
         if (void* Addr = ::GetProcAddress(*It, s.c_str())) {
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\cling\src\tools\cling\lib\Utils\PlatformWin.cpp:625:44: error: invalid conversion from 'FARPROC {aka int (__attribute__((__stdcall__)) *)()}' to 'v
oid*' [-fpermissive]
           if (void* Addr = ::GetProcAddress(Modules[i], s.c_str()))
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\cling\src\tools\cling\lib\Utils\PlatformWin.cpp: In function 'bool cling::utils::platform::Popen(const string&, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<char>&, bool)
':
```

I guess the `_MSC_VER` error is not a problem, I can fake some random version but what about the cast of `FARPROC` to `void*`?

Comment: As the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` are cached, did you deleted `CMakeCache.txt` in the build directory before adding `_DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fexceptions` to the cmake command line?

Comment: You really should add compile flags using the this command in your CMake file: `target_compile_options(YourTarget PRIVATE -fexceptions)`.

Comment: These flags are already added in [lib/Interpreter/CMakeLists.txt#L111](https://github.com/root-project/cling/blob/master/lib/Interpreter/CMakeLists.txt#L111) with `set_source_files_properties` command. But it seems that MinGW generator doesn't fall into `UNIX` category, for which these flags are added... It is strange that `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fexceptions"` doesn't help. Have you tried to run build process with `VERBOSE=1` option? So complete the command line will be printed, and you may check whether it has specific compiler flags.

Comment: From the verbose output I see that the flag `-fno-exceptions` is added, but no `-fexceptions`